# Ipv6 over bridged network stops working after some time (Ubuntu LXC)

Tags: ubuntu, ipv6, bridge, lxc

i hope you can help me. I am running several Linux Containers on a bare metal server which is provided with an Global Ipv6 address as well as an 64-bit network by my provider.

I have configured IPv6 settings within the config files of each container using a bridge provided by the host machine. When I reboot the whole system I am able to access my containers via IPv6 and vice versa (e.g. ping6 google.de works). After some time (dunno how long) the containers are no more accessible via their ipv6-address and I don't know why (ping6 google.de also doesn't work). Does anyone have a clue what could cause this behavior?

Here are my configs:

**network/interfaces (master)**

iface br0 inet6 static
pre-up modprobe ipv6
address 2a02:xxxx:1:1::517:f79
gateway 2a02:xxxx:1:1::1
netmask 64
bridge_stp on

**sysctl.conf (master)**

## ipv6 settings (no autoconfiguration)

net.ipv6.conf.default.autoconf=0
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra=0
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra_defrtr=0
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra_rtr_pref=0
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra_pinfo=0
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_source_route=0
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_redirects=0
net.ipv6.conf.default.forwarding=1
net.ipv6.conf.default.proxy_ndp=1
net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf=0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra=0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra_defrtr=0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra_rtr_pref=0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra_pinfo=0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_source_route=0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_redirects=0
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
net.ipv6.conf.all.proxy_ndp=1

**network/interfaces (container)**

## The loopback network interface

> auto lo 
>   iface lo inet loopback
>
> auto eth0
>   iface eth0 inet manual 
>   iface eth0 inet6 manual

**LXC-Container config**

## Network configuration

- lxc.network.type = veth
- lxc.network.flags = up
- lxc.network.link = br0
- lxc.network.hwaddr = 7e:7f:de:16:xx:xx
- lxc.network.ipv4.gateway = 81.7.xx.1
- lxc.network.ipv4 = 81.7.xx.xxx/24
- lxc.network.ipv6 = 2a02:xxxx:a:77::123/64

I would be very thankful for any advice.

Best,
Patrick

Comment: Is this on Hetzner or another provider?

Comment: It's on EUServ, but does it matter? The master server does not lose the ipv6 connection at all, only the containers :(

Comment: Yes it probably matters. Many such providers do slightly odd things to their networks that you have to work around. Hetzner is just a famous example. I'm not familiar with EUServ and my German is terrible, so I will have to leave this for someone else...

Comment: You might want to try your set-up on Linode. This IaaS provider has a sane and reliable way of handling multi-tenant IPv6 networking. I think you'd increase your odds of people being able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling multicast snooping:

```
echo -n 0 > /sys/class/net/<brif>/bridge/multicast_snooping
```

Or enabling multicast querier (very early):

```
echo -n 1 > /sys/class/net/<brif>/bridge/multicast_querier
```

https://askubuntu.com/a/688854/11831